# create EBS volume giving error for amazon ec2 using jclouds

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jclouds

I'm using the below code to create EBS volume in amazon ec2. The same code is in production and was working fine. But from last couple of days I'm getting a new exception. I cant find out the certain error. Please help to understand the error.

```
else if (cloudType.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase("AWS-EC2")) {
                EC2Api ec2Api = computeServiceContext.unwrapApi(EC2Api.class);
                LOG.info("initialized ec2 api for volume creation");

                org.jclouds.ec2.domain.Volume volume = ec2Api
                        .getElasticBlockStoreApi()
                        .get()
                        .createVolumeInAvailabilityZone(zoneId, size);

                ec2Api.getTagApi().get().applyToResources(ImmutableMap.of("Name",volumeName), ImmutableSet.of(volume.getId()));

                responseTemplate.setJobId(volume.getId());
                responseTemplate.setCreationTime(volume.getCreateTime());
                responseTemplate.setZoneId(volume.getAvailabilityZone());
            }
```

Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument at index 0 on invocation.getInvoked() public abstract org.jclouds.ec2.domain.Volume org.jclouds.ec2.features.ElasticBlockStoreApi.createVolumeInAvailabilityZone(java.lang.String,int) was null
```

Comment: hi.. can anyone please help out for the issue ?

Comment: Ya even we are facing this issue since a week. Looking for a solution :\